# How to control car racing games using kinect?

Tags: c#, uigesturerecognizer, kinect, game-development

I am trying to control some online flash racing games using kinect (using visual studio c#).
The user needs to hold his hands in air and act like he is behind a steering wheel of a car.
To increase the speed, the user needs to move the (imaginary) steering wheel away from his body.

The problem is, whenever I turn my car left or right, it remains to that side only..... It won't come back even after trying hard and turning the steering in the opposite direction.

I am using a class named VirtualKeyboard which has the methods for keyUp and keyDown.
Here is the complete code-

```
    /////////////// GAME MODE (Racing games)  /////////////////////////
                            if ((leftHand.Position.Y > hipCentre.Position.Y) &&         (rightHand.Position.Y > hipCentre.Position.Y))
                            {
                                //Keyboard.GetKeyStates();
                                if (Math.Abs(leftHand.Position.Y -         rightHand.Position.Y) > 0.15)
                                {
                                    if (leftHand.Position.Y > rightHand.Position.Y)
                                    {
                                        //System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("        {RIGHT}");
                                                VirtualKeyboard.KeyUp(System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Left);
                                                VirtualKeyboard.KeyDown(System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Right);

                                        message += System.Environment.NewLine + "Right         keys are pressed.";
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        //System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("        {LEFT}");
                                                VirtualKeyboard.KeyUp(System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Right);
                                                VirtualKeyboard.KeyDown(System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Left);

                                        message += System.Environment.NewLine + "Left         keys are pressed.";
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                            VirtualKeyboard.KeyUp(System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Right);
                                            VirtualKeyboard.KeyUp(System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Left);
                                }
                                if ((hipCentre.Position.Z - leftHand.Position.Z > 0.2)         && (hipCentre.Position.Z - rightHand.Position.Z > 0.2))
                                {
                                    //System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{UP}");
                                            VirtualKeyboard.KeyDown(System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Up);
                                    message += System.Environment.NewLine + "- UP         pressed -";
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                            VirtualKeyboard.KeyUp(System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Up);
                                }



                            }
```

And the VirtualKeyboard class is as follows-

```
    public static class VirtualKeyboard
        {
            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            static extern uint keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, int dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);
            public static void KeyDown(System.Windows.Forms.Keys key)
            {
                keybd_event((byte)key, 0, 0, 0);
            }

            public static void KeyUp(System.Windows.Forms.Keys key)
            {
                keybd_event((byte)key, 0, 0x7F, 0);
            }
        }
```

Any other of code is also welcome.
P.S. Sorry, i didn't comment the code :-P